# To find zero set of an convolution of two characteristics function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, convolution

For $E=[0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}, ~l>0$ and consider the function
$$\chi_{[-l,l]}*\chi_E(x)=\int_{-l}^{l}\chi_E(x-t)dt.$$
What is the zero set of the above function (in terms of $l$ may be)?

Notations: $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of rationals. $\chi_E$ is the characteristic function of $E.$

Edit after 1st answer: Let $f$ be any positive integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathcal{Z}_f$ is the zero set of $f$.  What is the zero set of
$$\chi_{[-l,l]}*f(x)?$$

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a null set, you can replace $\chi_E$ with $\chi_{[0,1]}$.

Comment: No, if for example $E$ is such that $E \cap I$ has positive measure for all nondegenerate intervals $I$, then $\chi_{[-l,l]} \ast \chi_E$ is positive everywhere.

Comment: You are right. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Fischer points out in the comments, the answer is the same if you replace $E$ by the interval $[0,1]$.  Now we can rewrite $\chi_{[0,1]}(x-t) = \chi_{[x-1,x]}(t)$, so the integral is
$$
\int_{-\ell}^{\ell} \chi_{[x-1,x]}(t) \,dt = m([-\ell,\ell] \cap [x-1,x])
$$
where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.  Therefore this function is equal to zero iff $x \leq -\ell$ or $x \geq \ell+1$.